# Flashing cursor on system boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, cursor

I'm trying to install the latest version of Ubuntu using a USB stick.
I had Windows 7 running normally when I installed Ubuntu. I created a primary-swap and logical-ext4 ( `/` ) partitions for Ubuntu. When I start the machine, all I see is a flashing cursor instead of the grub boot menu.

grub screenshot from Ubuntu live USB:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: After rebooting , are you able to login into Ubuntu directly ?
boot-repair log shows that there are no problems with your system

Comment: No, that's the problem. I can only boot the live-cd (try ubuntu without installing), not the operating system directly.

Comment: Did you remove the USB stick after rebooting ?

Comment: Yes and changed the first boot device.

Comment: Do you use efi secure boot or legacy boot?

Comment: On Phoenix BIOS I see "Legacy OS: Enabled"

Comment: Try installing grub legacy instead of grub2, Steps are posted in answer

Comment: Answer updated, follow steps and check whether it works. Also paste contents of /etc/default/grub file. Mount /dev/sda5 to some directory first and then browse /etc/default and paste contents of grub file

Comment: Check this site, I will remotely use your system 
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/ubuntu-remote-desktop-sharing/ . Just enable Remote Desktop and give me your ip address (by executing hostname -I
)

Comment: I can't at the moment, if you'll be available in like 2 hours from now?

Comment: But it is too late here, it is 1am. I will be available after 8 hours or more. Anyway, i am sorry that i couldn't help you.

Comment: If you want to help me via remote administration, tell me of a messaging service to communicate before getting there. I don't want to waste your time though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: I have no idea if it's the same case or not. I posted this question 8 years ago and I see that I selected a correct answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

The problem was with the BIOS of my Clevo brand laptop, model M765TU.

In the ftp servers of the company I found the newest BIOS, flashed it and the problem is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps :**

1) Boot from the USB Stick.

2) Open a Terminal and type in the following commands, noting that the first command will put you into the grub “prompt”, and the next 3 commands will be executed there. Also note that hd0,0 implies the first hard drive and the first partition on that drive, which is where you probably installed grub to during installation. If not, then adjust accordingly.

```
sudo grub

root (hd0,5)

setup (hd0)

exit
```

Comment: The root ext4 partition is sda5, so the command would be root (hd0,4)?

Comment: no it implies the drive where grub should be installed, primary partition i guess you should use (hd0,0)

Comment: I added a screenshot link in the OP (error 17)

Comment: what is output of sudo fdisk –l

Comment: sudo fdisk -l
http://i.imgur.com/kyfEDr6.png

Comment: i checked your pastebin file and i saw grub is installed at (hd0,msdos5)/boot. thus you should use root (hd0,5). I have updated the answer. Also tell me output of fdisk -l

Comment: OK, I tried hd0,5 and hd0,4 without success. http://i.imgur.com/pA2WbAX.png